# Initializing array with two pointers

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main() {
    int **matrix = {
        {1, 3, 2, 4},
        {3, 2, 4, 5},
        {9, 3, 2, 1}
    };

    getchar();
}
```

1. Why does this display warnings like "braces around scalar initializer"?
2. Why do I need to initialize multidimentional arrays with more than one pointers? (if you could give me some pretty easy-to-understand explanation on this one...)
3. If I'd want to use int matrix[3][4] instead of int **matrix...what would be a function parameter if I'd want to pass this array? `int[][]`?

Comment: I suggest you read [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), especially section 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int **` is a pointer type not an array type. Pointers are not arrays. Use type `int [3][4]`.

You cannot pass arrays to functions but you can pass a pointer to an array. A function declaration to pass a pointer to an array 4 of `int` would be:

```
void f(int arr[3][4]);
```

or

```
void f(int arr[][4]);
```

or

```
void f(int (*arr)[4]);
```

The three declarations are equivalent.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays, but they point to the beginning of the array, as far as I know. But still, question 3 remains :P